# Magento product save resets my attributes

Tags: magento, attributes, product

Hey guys i have an wierd issue with one of my product attributes. The attribute is called "toon_huurinfo" and is of type combobox.

The values are

- Ja (Value 7) (This is the default option)
- Nee (Value 6)

I have written an automated import from an xml file. The only thing the import does (And it does it well) is updating the name and prices of the product. How ever everytime i run my import the updated products have a reset value of "toon_huurinfo". Lets say i have a products with "Nee" selected, They will be "Ja" (Default value) after import. There is absolutely no way that i update "toon_huurinfo"

Attribuutcode: toon_huurinfo

Scope: system

Type: dropdown

Required: no

Apply to productgroup: all

Can you guys help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could show relevant part of your code that takes care of attribute update.

From what I read it sounds like it is working. If you have your product attribute before import set to "Nee" and after import it is set to "Ja" there is probably "Ja" value in your import file. But maybe I just didn't understand your question.

Anyway, you should assign your attribute value like this:

```
$product->settoon_huurinfo('Your value here');
```

OR

```
$product->setData(toon_huurinfo, 'Your value');
```

Hope it helps,
Matic

Comment: The thing is i DONT want magento to update this attribute but magento does it anyways. As you can see here http://pastebin.com/5PNFsuKG i am not touching the attribute toon_huurinfo at all. But everytime i do an update the attribute value changed for updated products from "Nee" (no) to "Ja" (Yes, This is the default value).

Comment: You just answered your question :)
"Ja" is default value. If not set, "Ja" will be used.

What you should do is:
1. read product option in a variable
2. write product option (value is in variable you read before)

This will enshure that you save product with values that were inserted before update.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the product model hasn't called the load() function.

So to update the attribute of a product, do:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productID);
```

To update a product from a collection list, do:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->load();
foreach($products as $product){
    $product->setData('your_attribute', 'new_value');
    $product->save();
}
```